# How can I insert jwt token needed for api authentication in api request header?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, api, http, jwt

I want to access my api that posts some data in a database. For api authentication I am using a jwt token. I am having problems putting a jwt token into a header of my request.

I am using aws api that envokes a lambda function which can access my database, and angular for frontend.

My angualar code is:

```
const request = {
      "header": new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+myVariables.jwt,

      }),

      "body": {
        ... //body part works
      }
    }
```

```
this.http.post(this.postBlogUrl, request).subscribe(
      res => {console.log("data posted to api"); window.location.reload();},
      err => {console.log("Error occured: " + err.message);}
    );
```

myVariable.jwt is an exported variable where I save signed users jwt token when they sign in.

this.postBlogUrl is an url link to my api

also the weird part is that when I try to console.log(request.header) I cannot see the authorization field
`console.log(request.header);`gives me: [console.log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLMdx.png)

When I try the same thing in POSTMAN and I specify header authorization in "header" section and not in request object it works perfectly. So how can I do the same in my angular app?

So how can I specify a header like in postman https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1kg9.jpg instead of including it in a requst?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You should use HttpInterceptor

The angular way of adding middleware into the http handling chain is [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor).

You basically write a class with an intercept() method:

```
@Injectable()
export class HeadersInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headers = req.headers.append('Authorization', myData);
    return next.handle(req.clone({ headers }));
  }
```

Then you inject it using the [HTTP_INTERCEPTORS](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HTTP_INTERCEPTORS) injection token.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked perfectly! Thanks for referring me to httpinterceptors.
One resource that helped me to understand interceptors: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suTtA0Hlwlk

Answer (score 0):

I think you have just a typo `header` instead of `headers`